# A proof of a theorem on the different in algebraic number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I asked this question in Stack Exchange, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144135/a-proof-of-a-theorem-on-the-different-in-algebraic-number-fields), but I got no answer so far.
I don't know any modern book on algebraic number theory which states the following theorem, let alone its proof except Takagi's book written in Japanese.
This is surprising to me, because I think the theorem is a fundamental fact in algebraic number theory.
I know a proof of this theorem which uses a somewhat complicated argument using the Kronecker's method on forms. Moreover I think I came up with a proof using p-adic completions.
So I'm looking for a proof using only ideals.
Since this is a theorem concerning only ideals, it would be nice to have a proof without p-adic completions(I think ideals are more concrete than p-adic numbers).

**Theorem**
Let $K ⊂ L ⊂ E$ be a tower of algebraic number fields.
Suppose that $E/K$ is a Galois extension.
Let $B$ and $C$ be the rings of algebraic integers in $L$ and $E$ respectively.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $E/K$.
Let $H$ be the Galois group of $E/L$.
Let $G/H$ be the set of left cosets of $G$ by $H$.
Let $S$ be the set of representatives of $G/H$ - {$H$}. 
For each $\sigma ∈ S$, Let $J_\sigma$ be the ideal of $C$ generated by the set {$x - \sigma(x); x ∈ B$}.
Let $J$ be $\prod_{\sigma ∈ S}J_\sigma$.
Let $D_{L/K}$ be the [different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal).
Then $(D_{L/K})C = J$.

As a corollary to this theorem, we get the following useful result.

**Corollary**
Let $L$ be a finite Galois extension of an algebraic number field K.
Let $B$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $L$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $L/K$.
For each $\sigma ∈ G$ - {1}, Let $J_\sigma$ be the ideal of $B$ genertated by the set {$x - \sigma(x); x ∈ B$}.
Let $D_{L/K}$ be the different.
Then $D_{L/K} = \prod_{\sigma ∈ G - \{1\}}J_\sigma$.

Comment: Of course it is a matter of taste, but one of the charms, to me, of mathematics is the surprise that new ideas and methods sometimes usefully bear upon pre-existing questions... that made no mention of the "new" ideas.

For example, the Iwasawa-Tate treatment of "abelian" zeta and L-functions is much clearer, in the end, than Hecke's classical treatment (although Hecke's papers were very well written!) In particular, "Fujisaki's Compactness Lemma" gives the clearest proof of Dirichlet Units _and_ finiteness of class numbers. Elementariness is not always simplicity.

Comment: From a reverse-mathematical perspective, knowing the result doesn't rely on p-adic completions is a great help!

Comment: David, note that there is already a proof not based on $p$-adic completions (using "Kronecker's method on forms"). I believe the OP wants a simpler, but still classical, proof.

Comment: I agree with Paul Garrett; a proof using $p$-adic completions is likely to be conceptually simpler and more edifying that a proof  artificially phrased in the language of ideals.  So you should be happy with your $p$-adic proof.

Comment: In the analogy of Paul Garrett, since I only know the Iwasawa-Tate treatment of L-functions, I'd like to know the Hecke's classical treatment.

Comment: For the question on different, You may check Shimura's book on Arithmetic of quadratic forms (2010). For Hecke's proof of meromorphic continuous, check Neukirch's book on algebraic numbers. BTW. I am very interested in Takagi's book , is there an English or Chinese translation ? 

Comment: Thanks for the input. As far as I know, there's no translation of the Takagi's book on algebraic number theory which I think is a masterpiece.

Comment: @unknown Could you tell me the page number of the Shimura's book?
I borrowed his book, but could not find the relevant theorem.

Comment: Discussion Around Themrem 14.4

Comment: @unknown It's relevant but I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for. Thanks, any way.